# Function to sum and compare two sides of an array

Tags: python, arrays

For example this is `array = [1,2,3,4,3,2,1]`
i want computer to choose `i=4` and sum both left of the four and right of the four and then compare if they are equal to each other, program prints i value to the screen. 
Now i write it in here and it works as long as the i value is 0 but if i want to make this search for `i>0` then i gets complicated.

this is my main program:

```py
# importing "array" for array creations
import array as arr

# Function to find sum  
# of array exlcuding the  
# range which has [a, b]  
def sumexcludingrange(li, a, b): # I FOUND THIS FUNCTION ONLINE BUT ALSO DIDN`T WORK EITHER.

    sum = 0 
    add = True

    # loop in li 
    for no in li: 

         # if no != a then add 
        if no != a and add == True: 
            sum = sum + no 

        # mark when a and b are found  
        elif no == a: 
            add = False
        elif no == b: 
            add = True

    # print sum 
    return sum 



#lis = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6] 
#a = 2
#b = 5

#sumexcludingrange(arr, 0, i-1) 


def my(arr):

    for i in range(len(arr)):   
        if i == 0: #this works when array is like [1,0,0,1] and i equals zero
         sum_left = arr[0]
         sum_right = sum(arr) - arr[0]
         while sum_left == sum_right:
           print(i)
           break
        elif i > 0 : # i 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.. 
          #sumleft and sumright are not right.. what is the issue here?          
          sum_left = sumexcludingrange(arr, 0, i-1)  #result is 16, sumexcludingrange function didn`t 
                                                      #work.
          print (sum_left)
          #print(i)

          sum_right == sum(arr) - sum_left
          #print(sum_right)
          #break
          while sum_left == sum_right:
            print(sum_left)
            print(sum_right)
            print("they are equal now")
            break

        else:
          print("index cannot be a negative number.")

something = arr.array('i', [1,2,3,4,3,2,1]) # len(arr) = 7
my(something)
```

After seeing that i need another function to compare two sides of the array, i created a new file and write it in here and somehow it outputs this:
1
13
13
2
10
10

```
#array[i] array[i+1] .. + array[length-1]
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]  # 7 element so  length=7, 
for i in range(len(array)):  
 if i > 0 :
        ln = len(array) + 1
        sum_right = sum(array[i+1:ln])
        sum_left = sum(array) - sum_right
        print(i)
        print(sum_right)
        print(sum_right)
```

the way i think is  this:

```
# array[i]   i>0 i={1,2,3,4..}
sum_total = sum(arr) = array[0] + ..+ array[i-1] + array[i] + array[i+1] + ... + array[length-1]
sum_right = array[i+1] + .. + array[length-1]
sum_left = sum_total - sum_right
```

Is there a better way to accomplish that?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: which part do you mean?

Comment: try copy-pasting your code on a fresh interpreter and you will see what people trying to reproduce your code get

Comment: it is working. i don`t see any problem with indentiation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the solution could be something like this:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

a1 = array[:4] # first 4 numbers
a2 = array[-4:] # last 4 numbers

total = sum(array)
diff = total-sum(a2)
```

Comment: yes but we don`t know if it is gonna be four because [1,2,3,4,3,2,1 ] here if i separate 4 on the left side 1+2+3 = 3 + 2 + 1 right side.

Comment: So you want to separate by the number of digits in the array or by some specify number?